# Is it possible to create a 301 redirect and MX records at a naked domain?

Tags: web-hosting, dns, 301-redirect

I'm wondering since I found out that [creating a CNAME and an MX record is not allowed](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/880/blogger-and-google-app-hosting-at-naked-domain-using-11/949#949).

I want to create a 301 redirect from `example.com` to `www.example.com`, and have email with `@example.com` addresses.

I'm using 1&1 as my registrar, btw.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do 301 redirects, you'll need to have an A record that points to a valid web server. You can then instruct the web server to redirect people, eg. with Apache's .htaccess:

```
Redirect 301 / http://www.example.com
```

MX records can be created as usual.

Comment: I was also able to do this directly in 1&1 by choosing a "destination" for the domain. The tech support guy I talked to said that it does use a 301 redirect.

Comment: Ah, yeah, I should've mentioned that most hosting companies have some kind of easy redirect setup. This is what it's doing under the covers.